# Error: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/pubnub/api/AbstractLogger.class

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, pubnub

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/pubnub/api/AbstractLogger.class

i am facing this error while building the gradle can anyone help me out.????

Comment: You are adding the same library twice. Post your build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.atlanticlab.pubnubmaptracker"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

            // Enabling multidex support.
            multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android-debug:3.7.10'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.10'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```